# Div superior fijo se "corre" cuando el menu lateral izquierdo se expande

Tags: html, css, angular7, ngx-admin

estoy teniendo un inconveniente con una page de ngx-admin creada por mi. He creado un div fijo, que no se mueve a modo de encabezado, para que cuando el usuario scrolea ese div quede siempre a tope y asi siempre se vea la informacion de mi tramite. Hasta aca todo bien. El inconveniente se plantea cuando el usuario expande el menú lateral izquierdo. Toda la parte de la page responde bien, excepto el div fijo que puse yo arriba. Les dejo la siguiente imagen, donde se muestra cuando todo se ve lindo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando yo expando el menú lateral izquierdo, sucede esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El css del div superior es el siguiente:

```
.superior {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #f1f5f8;
    width: 92%;
    height: 200px;
    top: 3rem;
    border-bottom: $rojo-claro dotted 1px;
}
```

La verdad es que soy muy novato con css y no encontré la forma de solucionarlo. Probé de quitarle el "width: 92%" y mejora, pero no cubre todo el ancho de la pantalla. Realmente no sé como decirle que si el menu está expandido, que el ancho sea otro.
Otra cosa que intenté fue ponerle un z-index grande al menu lateral izquierdo, pero nunca me respondió ese intento.
Espero me puedan dar una mano, es importantisimo que lo solucione. Si necesitan mas codigo, por favor me lo piden que edito y agrego. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Prueba a añadirle `left: 0;` al css

Comment: sucede que al ponerle Left: 0 al css ese div superior tapa al menú lateral izquierdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion que le encontré fue ponerlo como sticky con left 0. Quedó asi y funciona bien:

```
.superior {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #f1f5f8;
    width: 92%;
    height: 200px;
    top: 3rem;
    border-bottom: $rojo-claro dotted 1px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Espero le sirva a alguien.